# Fire script after search and strip css

Tags: java, css, search, removeclass, removeall

Im looking for a way to strip css from content that is being pull from around the web.

1. A user type in car in my search field.
2. The site gets som conctent about cars.
3. I then want to take that content and strip the css(class and id's) and apply my styles.

The idea is that i link to the pages that has the content. The list i im getting now has it's own styling. Basically i want to make that conctent i am getting a preview of to match my sites design

I am getting the content in div's

Comment: Basically you are saying that you want to steal content from another author and make it look like your own. I doubt that this is possible

Comment: there is not enough information in the question, example data would have been handy. Is the input data always in the same format? Is the input data XHTML? Can you not scrape the individual fields and then create new html with all your styling just injecting the scrapped text and images?

Comment: Thats one way to put it but thats not what i am looking for. 
The idea is that i link to the pages that has the content. The list i im getting now has it's own styling. Basically i want to make that concten i am getting a preview of to match my sites design

Comment: Bearing in mind the content you pull is likely to only make visual sense in conjunction with the CSS you want to strip- applying your own styles is likely to be incredibly hit and miss for producing visually coherant output..

Comment: Agree with @ExtPro. You could make the content look meaningless. What is the purpose, may be there is a different solution... You could snapshot the site and display that in your <div>